# Magento - duplicate quote item to new row and new price

Tags: php, magento

I have an observer where I add a new quote item when the qty is more than one. Heres the code I use to create this quote item:

```
$quote_item = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item');
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($oldQuoteItem->getProduct()->getId());
$quote_item->setProduct($_product);
$quote_item->setQuote($quote);
$quote_item->setOriginalCustomPrice($oldQuoteItem->getProduct()->getPrice());
$quote_item->save();
```

It work's fine for simple products, but when I will duplicate a quote item with a configurable product, it will only take the parent product, and not the simple product that belongs to it, and therefore I get an error where the product is not on stock.

Anyone who got an idea, on how to duplicate the excact product to the new quote item ?

Answer (score 2):

I have had success with the following for all product types.

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$oldQuoteItem = $quote->getItemById(ITEM_ID);

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->load($oldQuoteItem->getProductId());

$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$cart->addProduct($product, $oldQuoteItem->getBuyRequest());
$cart->save();
```

You should be able to then modify the item price.

Bear in mind if you want to do this for multiple products you must only save the cart once at the end after every $cart->addProduct()